# Ros callback function parameter explained

Tags: c++, ros

Why in ROS when you do call a callback function there is the header as following:

```
void error_sub(const std_msgs::UInt16::ConstPtr& msg);
```

From the following definition

```
void error_sub(const std_msgs::UInt16::ConstPtr& msg)
 {
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%d]", msg->data);
    error = msg->data;
 }
```

Where is the problem if you just delcare it as:

```
void error_sub(const std_msgs::UInt16& msg);
```

And define it as:

```
void error_sub(const std_msgs::UInt16& msg)
 {
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%d]", msg.data);
    error = msg.data;
 }
```

Comment: `void error_sub(const std_msgs::UInt16::ConstPtr& msg);` function declaration - header.

Comment: Put it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one will work, because of how `ParameterAdapter` is used to call the subscription callback. In fact, there are many possible callback function signatures:

```
void callback(const boost::shared_ptr<M const>&);  // (const M::ConstPtr&)
void callback(const boost::shared_ptr<M>&);        // (const M::Ptr&)
void callback(boost::shared_ptr<M const>);         // (M::ConstPtr)
void callback(boost::shared_ptr<M>);               // (M::Ptr)
void callback(const M&);
void callback(M);
void callback(const MessageEvent<M const>&);
void callback(const MessageEvent<M>&);
```

- https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/060fd7653450de9c411a90a5a22188b4e06d2b90/clients/roscpp/include/ros/subscription_callback_helper.h#L144
- https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/060fd7653450de9c411a90a5a22188b4e06d2b90/clients/roscpp/include/ros/parameter_adapter.h#L56-L66

Using `M::ConstPtr` (aka `shared_ptr<const M>`) instead of `const M&` is potentially more efficient because if you want to store the whole message and use it later, you can simply copy the shared_ptr. In your example, since you are just accessing `msg.data`, it doesn't matter. If your callback takes `M` instead of `const M&`, then ROS would be forced to copy the message.

Comment: It could also take `M&` and the efficiency would be the same, right? With the cost of possibly loosing data (if anyone would modify the variable)

Comment: I'm not quite sure because `M&` isn't listed as one of the supported options. It might work, but note that [MessageEvent::getMessage() will sometimes copy the message](https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/blob/4c2c46243f5d83b356f2ca87088529c6b25454b1/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_event.h#L160) if necessary. Anyway, I wouldn't recommend using `M&` as a signature because it implies that you intend to modify the incoming message.

Comment: Is there any way to better understand all "snake" `elem::elem::elem` ? Is there any API docs that shows what to call and when? Thanks

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what you’re asking. Does this help? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-operator-in-c/